# Function returning single row from a table

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Can't for the life of me get this function to properly return a row (it will only return one as I am querying on the primary key). It looks like this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sch.getrow(
    IN gy integer,
    IN gw integer,
    IN pi uuid)
RETURNS SETOF record AS $$

BEGIN

EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM sch.foo WHERE gy = $1 AND gw = $2 AND idpi = $3' INTO record USING gy, gw, pi;

END

$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

Trying various `RETURN EXECUTE` and `RETURN QUERY` etc, but nada: the SQL string will be a dynamically defined string as the table name will end up changing based on the input variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function returns `SETOF` you can use `RETURN QUERY` regardless of how many rows (one or more) the function can return.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sch.getrow(
    IN gy integer,
    IN gw integer,
    IN pi uuid)
RETURNS SETOF record AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM sch.foo WHERE gy = $1 AND gw = $2 AND idpi = $3' USING gy, gw, pi;

END

$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Not related but important. The function should not be defined as `IMMUTABLE` because its results depend on data stored in a table. Per [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html)

> IMMUTABLE indicates that the function cannot modify the database and always returns the same result when given the same argument values; that is, it does not do database lookups or otherwise use information not directly present in its argument list.